# How to use a variable in lm() function in R?

Tags: r, lm

Let us say I have a dataframe (df) with two columns called "height" and "weight".

Let's say I define:

```
x = "height"
```

How do I use x within my `lm()` function?  Neither `df[x]` nor just using x works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways :

Create a formula with `paste`

```
x = "height"
lm(paste0(x, '~', 'weight'), df)
```

Or use `reformulate`

```
lm(reformulate("weight", x), df)
```

---

Using reproducible example with `mtcars` dataset :

```
x = "Cyl"
lm(paste0(x, '~', 'mpg'), data = mtcars)

#Call:
#lm(formula = paste0(x, "~", "mpg"), data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          mpg  
#    11.2607      -0.2525
```

and same with

```
lm(reformulate("mpg", x), mtcars)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `glue` to create the formula

```
x <- "height"
lm(glue::glue('{x} ~ weight'), data = df)
```

---

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
x <- 'cyl'
lm(glue::glue('{x} ~ mpg'), data = mtcars)

#Call:
#lm(formula = glue::glue("{x} ~ mpg"), data = mtcars)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          mpg  
#    11.2607      -0.2525
```

Comment: I think this is actually the most elegant solution. I would add that if one has already loaded ```tidyverse```, then ```str_glue``` will already be available from the ```stringr``` package. I believe it's in fact a thing wrapper around ```glue::glue``` but it may save one dependence on a given project.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `x = "height"` your are assigning a string of characters to the variable `x`.

Consider this data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  height = c(176, 188, 165),
  weight = c(75, 80, 66)
)
```

If you want a regression using `height` and `weight` you can either do this:

```r
lm(height ~ weight, data = df)

# Call:
#   lm(formula = height ~ weight, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)       weight  
#        59.003        1.593
```

or this:

```r
lm(df$height ~ df$weight)

# Call:
#   lm(formula = df$height ~ df$weight)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)    df$weight  
#        59.003        1.593
```

If you really want to use `x` instead of `height`, you must have a variable called `x` (in your `df` or in your environment). You can do that by creating a new variable:

```r
x <-  df$height
y <- df$weight

lm(x ~ y)  

# Call:
#   lm(formula = x ~ y)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)            y  
#        59.003        1.593
```

Or by changing the names of existing variables:

```r
names(df) <- c("x", "y")
lm(x ~ y, data = df)

# Call:
#   lm(formula = x ~ y, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)            y  
#        59.003        1.593
```